# Porting data from SQLServer to BigData

Tags: python, sql-server, bigdata

I have a large SQLServer database on my current hosting site...
and

I would like to import it into Google BigData.

Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is that there is no general recipe for doing this.  In fact, I don't even think it makes sense to have a general recipe ...

What you need to do is to analyse the SQL schemas and work out an appropriate mapping to BigData schemas.  Then you figure out how to migrate the data.